# Remove first character from a string using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, grid

I am using the below code to delete my grid rows. Also I need to remove $ symbol, because when removing it causes problems while deleting. 
 I used this code to replace $ sign to empty space and it doesn't help. Can anyone correct me?

```
 string Dollar = Dollars.Text.ToString();
 string dolreplace = Dollar.Substring(1, Dollar.Length - 1);
```

So I need to remove the dollar symbol appearing for Dollar column.

```
protected void Details_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Label ECode = (Label)Details.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblCode");
    Label Dollars = (Label)Details.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblDollars");
    string Dollar = Dollars.Text.ToString();
    string RemoveDollar = Dollar.Substring(1, Dollar.Length - 1);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Application where Code= @Code and Dollar_Amount= @Dollars", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", Convert.ToDouble(Code.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dollars", Convert.ToInt32(RemoveDollar));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Deleted successfully');", true);
    BindGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem :** You are Converting/Assigning `Label` into string variable.

**Solution :** you need to use `Text` property of the Label to assign its value `(Dollars.Text)` into String variable.

**Solution 1:**

Replace This:

```
string Dollar = Dollars.ToString();
```

With This:

```
string Dollar = Dollars.Text.ToString();
```

OR

**Solution 2:** if you want to remove first character you use `Substring()` function

```
string Dollar = Dollars.Text.ToString();
string dolreplace = Dollar.Substring(1, Dollar.Length-1);
```

**Solution 3:** You are enclosing double and int values within single quotes. you need to enclose only String types within single quotes.

your uery is open to `SQL Injection Attacks`. so i would suggest you to use `parameterised queries` to avoid them.

Try this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Application where Code= @Code and Yearly_Dollar_Amount= @DollarAmt", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code",Convert.ToDouble(Code.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DollarAmt",int.Parse(dolreplace,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: yeah but still I 'm unable to delete the row with my conditions.

Comment: @user3279082: check my edited answer with `solution2`

Comment: Its really not happening. Still unable to delete the rows in grid.

Comment: @user3279082: how are you verifying wether its working or not? debugging it ? if not please debug and see what is the exact value of `dolereplace` varibale.

Comment: @user3279082: ok thats a different story but you are able to remove the dollar, so tell me what are the data types of `code` and `doller` in database table

Comment: Code is float and dollar is int

Comment: With having int how are you display dollar symbols in the page. Any casting?

Comment: I am converting and displaying it.

Comment: Why not change the datatype to money?

Comment: @user3279082: check my edited answer with `solution3`

Comment: unable to delete still

Comment: @user3279082: are you sure that there is an equalnet record in database with your dollar amount and code?

Comment: Yes I am sure, there are records which are equal to my query.

Comment: @user3279082: can you debug till sql query and see what are actual values of code and dolarreplace, if possible post the snapshot

Comment: //getting error here.. input was not in correct format // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dollars", Convert.ToInt32(RemoveDollar));

Comment: It looks like you are pointing to a wrong table or check your connection string.

Comment: @user3279082: please debug and see what is the actual value of `replacedolar`.

Comment: @Sudhakar: All values are fetching perfectly but fails to delete. Dollar symbol is getting deleted in replacedollar. But I get this error "Input string was not in a correct format" in this line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DollarAmt",Convert.ToInt32(dolreplace));

Comment: @user3279082: i strongly belive that `replacedolar` variable has some alphabets or whitespace or some invalid chars , can u debug and tell me what is the exact value of the `replacedolar`?

Comment: replace dollar is null in this line string replacedollar = Dollar.Substring(2, Dollar.Length - 2); and in this line I can see the dollar value showing up like this "190,000"...... cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dollars", Convert.ToInt32(RemoveDollar));.. Also my dollar value is display like this $ 190,000 in the Grid

Comment: its okay,before assigning value it should have `null` but are you sure you are using -> `string replacedollar = Dollar.Substring(1, Dollar.Length - 1);`? because in ur comment its 2 instead of 1? btw in whihc culture u are in?

Comment: I am using 2 as of now to remove white space after $. Is it correct?

Comment: @user3279082: ohh, great then it is fine. BTW in which Culture ur in?

Comment: imean from which country ur in? different countries follow different formats.

Comment: I am from India(Noida).

Comment: @user3279082: check my edited answer with `soulution3`

Comment: still no luck and get this error "Input string was not in a correct format". I am gettng exhausted and I think I'm making you too.

Comment: are you sure you are getting `190,000` after removal of dollar sign because as ur in indian culture it should give you `190000` without comma

Comment: So I have to remove comma now?

Comment: Thanks a lot sudhakar for helping me out.

Comment: @user3279082: does user enters comma as part of value?

Comment: No they dont enter. Commas are seperated using conversion

Comment: @user3279082: ok then no problem :) all the best.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: I working on update query for the same grid and I'm not able to update dollar column and the rest are fine. Can you assist me?

Comment: @user3279082: better rise a question , i will see if i can help you.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: Here is the link to my new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846082/unable-to-update-converted-datatype-column

Comment: Dollar.Substring(1, Dollar.Length-1) removes first and last characters. Should be Dollar.Substring(1, Dollar.Length) to remove the first character only.